# Has Robert Kirkman ever commented on whether humans can safely consume zombie meat?

Tags: the-walking-dead, zombie, food, fear-the-walking-dead, robert-kirkman

I want to know if there's word of god to be had here.

What I did find is close, but not quite definitive:

- Animals can eat zombies
- Animals can drink zombie-contaminated water
- Kirkman says people can safely eat other humans who have been bitten, but haven't turned yet (but doesn't say you can eat actual zombie flesh)
- Kirkman says that drinking a bit of zombie blood isn't the end of the world (no pun intended)

So I'm looking for the missing piece of the puzzle:

### Has *Robert Kirkman himself* ever commented on what would happen if a human ate zombie meat?

*Note: I'm not interested in eating bitten people, or drinking a little zombie blood, because I have already read his comments on those subjects; I'm also not interested in what anyone other than Kirkman himself has said.*

Comment: I'm confused, are you crowdsourcing your answer for M&TV SE?

Comment: @kuhl - No, this is about my own curiosity.  If anyone comes up with something conclusive, and if I decide to use it in that answer, I will give the user attribution in the M&TV answer, and give them a bounty.

Comment: I don't know about their eating of zombies, but most zombie apocolypse survivors shy away from clown meat. It tastes funny.

Comment: Related: [Can a zombie be eaten?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/17576/49)